# Somehow unexisting book even though volume 2 exists

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I am desperately trying to find a book

```
Electromagnetic Interactions of Hadrons, Vol.1, A Donnachie; G Shaw; New York 1978
```

Somehow, the second volume is easily found: https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781475707151. It can also easily be found freely on the web. And if you look on page XV, you can find the contents of Vol.1. So it looks like there was a Volume 1. Vol.1 is also referenced in some papers. But somehow it does not seem to exist!

Some web pages give its contents (see for example:)

- http://www.hep.manchester.ac.uk/u/graham/embooks/outline.html
- http://inspirehep.net/search?ln=fr&p=Donnachie+Shaw+Lyth&of=hb&action_search=Recherche&sf=earliestdate&so=d

Do you have any idea where I could look? Or what could have happened to this book? Volume 2 keeps on referencing to some papers in volume 1 so I would like to have a look.

Comment: Perhaps one could look in a library. The first (semi-random) university library catalog I checked had it.

Comment: Could it be that they came out with https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781475707151 , and then a second  book became volume 2, and they refer to the first as volume 1?